# Not able to use the mounted directory inside docker container

Tags: docker, mount, docker-volume

I tried to spin up the machine which NFS attached to it. And on NFS I have a folder /mnt/efs/efs
And inside that, I have project specific structure.

[image]

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/mnt",
                "Destination": "/mnt",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

I want to use that mounted directory within my docker container I am trying to use it something like this but it says that files do not exist.

```
docker run -it dockerimage:test --mount type=bind,source=/mnt,target=/mnt  -e mnh="/mnt/efs/efs/crl/test1.text" -e nw="/mnt/efs/efs/crl/test2.txt"
```

What is the correct way of passing environment variables to the container?

Comment: Docker-specific options like `--mount` and `-e` need to be _before_ the image name; as you've specified them here they provide the command for the container to run.

Comment: It still doesn't find the files. Would it be another issue related to the directory? I am using aws ec2 instance and efs file store here.